# 403 Error on Angular 2 Website that is generated using angular-cli and IIS 7.5

Tags: node.js, angular, iis-7.5, angular-cli

I have my website that created by angular-cli tool. It works perfectly fine on localhost. However, when I deploy it to IIS 7.5, it gives me 403 error. What I did was to deploy another angular 2 website in the same folder with not using cli tool and it worked. So I'm thinking I don't have permission error. Somehow none of the angular 2 websites that generated by cli tool doesn't work on IIS 7.5 . I have my package.json file below.

```
{
  "name": "myauthapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
     "start": "ng serve",
      "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\" --project src/tsconfig.json --type-       check && tslint \"e2e/**/*.ts\" --project e2e/tsconfig.json --type-check",
       "test": "ng test",
       "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko    false",
       "e2e": "protractor"
   },
      "private": true,
       "dependencies": {
      "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
      "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
       "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
       "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
       "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
       "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
       "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
       "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
       "angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.7",
       "core-js": "^2.4.1",
       "firebase": "^3.6.5",
       "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
       "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
       "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
    },
      "devDependencies": {
       "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
       "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
       "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
       "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.25.5",
       "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
       "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
        "karma": "1.2.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
        "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
        "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
        "protractor": "~4.0.13",
        "ts-node": "1.2.1",
        "tslint": "^4.3.0",
        "typescript": "~2.0.3"
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why angular-cli makes this problem. But the simple solution is to run **ng build** command. It created a **dist** folder. IIS website source should also be directed to the dist folder.

Comment: are you directing the IIS website folder url to your dist folder..??

Comment: Initially, it was directed to the website folder. That was the mistake. It's supposed to be directed to the dist folder. However, my other angular website that I didn't use angular-cli worked fine without directing to the dist folder. In fact, I didn't even use **ng build** command.

Comment: Can you create another folder and copy the contents of dist folder into it and make that folder as your website path.... everytime the dist folder gets retreated when you do  ng build , maybe that cab be the issue.